# connect to mysql from spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to follow the instructions mentioned here...

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/08/17/apache-spark-makes-slow-mysql-queries-10x-faster/

and here...

https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/10/07/using-apache-spark-mysql-data-analysis/

---

I am using sparkdocker image.

```
docker run -it -p 8088:8088 -p 8042:8042 -p 4040:4040 -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 bash

cd /usr/local/spark/

./sbin/start-master.sh

./bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --master local
```

This works as expected:

```
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).count()
```

But this shows an error:

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" ->  "jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4:3306/test?user=dba&password=dba123",
  "dbtable" -> "ontime.ontime_part",
  "fetchSize" -> "10000",
  "partitionColumn" -> "yeard", "lowerBound" -> "1988", "upperBound" -> "2016", "numPartitions" -> "28"
  )).load()
```

And here is the error:

```
<console>:25: error: not found: value spark
         val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
```

How do I connect to MySQL from within spark shell?

Comment: Which version of spark are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

With spark 2.0.x,you can use DataFrameReader and DataFrameWriter.
Use SparkSession.read to access DataFrameReader and use Dataset.write to access DataFrameWriter.

Suppose using spark-shell.

### read example

```
val prop=new java.util.Properties()
prop.put("user","username")
prop.put("password","yourpassword")
val url="jdbc:mysql://host:port/db_name"

val df=spark.read.jdbc(url,"table_name",prop) 
df.show()
```

### read example 2

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", “schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
```

from [spark doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)

### write example

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val prop=new java.util.Properties()
prop.put("user","username")
prop.put("password","yourpassword")
val url="jdbc:mysql://host:port/db_name"
//df is a dataframe contains the data which you want to write.
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url,"table_name",prop)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `spark` is not defined, you should use the `SQLContext` to connect to the driver like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val dataframe_mysql = sqlcontext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://Public_IP:3306/DB_NAME").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "tblage").option("user", "sqluser").option("password", "sqluser").load()
```

Later you can user `sqlcontext` where you used spark (in spark.read etc)

Answer (score 0):

- Create the spark context first
- Make sure you have jdbc jar files in attached to your classpath

if you are trying to read data from jdbc. use dataframe API instead of RDD as dataframes have better performance. refer to the below performance comparsion graph.

[image: DataFrame vs RDD]

here is the syntax for reading from jdbc

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("app"))
                .setMaster("local[2]")
                .set("spark.serializer",prop.getProperty("spark.serializer"));

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
sqlCtx = new SQLContext(sc);

df = sqlCtx.read()
                        .format("jdbc")
                        .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4:3306/test")
                        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                        .option("dbtable","dbtable")
                        .option("user", "dbuser")
                        .option("password","dbpwd"))
                        .load();
```

Comment: I don't see how the part on performance is relevant to the question. The graph describes performance differences between RDDs and DF on aggregations. Plus the question is about connecting spark to MySQL in spark-shell which is a Scala REPL and your answer is in Java...

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem for those migrating to Spark 2.0.0 from the earlier versions. The Spark documentation is not very good. To solve this, you have to define a SparkSession, like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL Example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()
```

This solution is hidden in the Spark SQL, Dataframes and Data Sets Guide [located here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#getting-started). SparkSession is the new entry point to the DataFrame API and it incorporates both *SQLContext* and *HiveContext* and has some additional advantages, so there is no need to define either of those anymore. Further information about this can be [found here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/6122906529858466/431554386690884/4814681571895601/latest.html).

Please accept this as the answer, if you find this useful.